# How display / set image for printing, in size cm what i want?

Tags: image

I have image png in resolution 829x597 generated by php gd.

How force user browser, to **print it** in dimensions 11.5 cm width 7.5cm height. ?

User hit, ctrl + p, hit print, and output image on paper should have 11.5cm x 7.5 cm

Please help
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you're talking about from a browser, in which case, you can't directly, as PNG doesn't store print resolution.

However, if you embed the PNG in a webpage and specify its width in inches/cm/pt, then the browser will respect that and print it at the correct pixel density.

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of printing 100 pages with other dimensions, for example in pt, i finally found where problem is.
So i have inside CSS information width:10.5cm; height:7.5cm;

Chromium browser will print 12cm ^^ and 8cm heigh...

After change to firefox, everything work well...

It's some kind of a browser bug... i was thinking that's my problem... but as You can see... it's browser...